# Time-series with multiple 'active' or 'inactive' states in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database

I have a database that stores for each minute in a large timespan some empirical data. The time could be the primary key of the table, i.e. each minute occurs at most once (even exactly once).

Also, I can say for each minute that several 'states' might be active. There are times when no states are active, there are times where one state is active, and there are times when multiple states are active.

The number of possible states is quite large (some 40 states). How could I model the time series of empirical data with states in one table? I want to be able to filter the minutes where e.g. multiple states are active, or where one or more 'interesting' states are active.

The database is quite intricate. There is much more data and I have a lot of views. To keep it simple, I want to get rid of some 'join-on-this, group-by' stuff. Of course I could join with the table containing the states, but in the joined table, the time would become non-unique (since there are times when more than one state is active).

The obvious simple idea would be to have for each state another column that can hold the two values 'active' or 'inactive' (or just 'active' and 'NULL'). But since I have some 40 states, that would mean some 40 more columns....

What is the best way to model this in a SQL database. I want to use SQLite3 by the way....

Answer (score 1):

A column value that is NULL, 0, or 1 will occupy only one byte in the database.

If you normalize the database so that each active state gets its own row, then each such row must also store the minute it belongs to.
Unless there are very few active states, it is likely that this will need more space than the 40 columns.

If you have 40 columns, it will not be easy to count how many states are active in a minute.